# Approximation of Nearly Circular Orbit by a Precessing Ellipse

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, gravity, orbital-motion

I am self-studying the 3rd edition of Goldstein's *Classical Mechanics* and have hit a roadblock when working a problem (Chapter 3, Problem 20). The problem asks us to consider a planet of mass $m$ orbiting the Sun, but with an additional force (small compared to gravity) given by

\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{F} = -mC\mathbf{r}
\end{equation*}

where $C$ is a constant. The problem asks the reader to (a) calculate the period for a circular orbit of radius $r_{0}$ of the planet in this combined field; (b) calculate the period of radial oscillations for slight disturbances from this circular orbit; and (c) to show that nearly circular orbits can be approximated by a precessing ellipse and to find the precession frequency. Parts (a) and (b) seem straightforward, but I'll include my reasoning anyway. The equivalent one-dimensional potential is given by

\begin{equation*}
V'(r) = -\frac{k}{r} + \frac{1}{2}mCr^{2} + \frac{\ell^{2}}{2\mu r^{2}}
\end{equation*}

where $\mu$ is the reduced mass of the planet-Sun system. For the orbit to be circular, we must have

\begin{equation*}
-\frac{\partial V'}{\partial r}\biggr\rvert_{r=r_{0}} = 0.
\end{equation*}

This, together with the integral of motion $\ell = \mu r^{2}\dot{\theta}$ implies that

\begin{equation*}
\dot{\theta} = \sqrt{\frac{m}{\mu}}\sqrt{\frac{k}{mr_{0}^{3}} + C}
\end{equation*}

and the period is calculated as $\tau = 2\pi/\dot{\theta}$. To calculate the period of radial oscillation for a nearly circular orbit, put $r\mapsto r_{0}+x$ in the radial equation of motion to obtain

\begin{align*}
\mu \ddot{x} &= -\frac{k}{(r_{0}+x)^{2}} - Cm(r_{0}+x) + \frac{\ell^{2}}{\mu (r_{0}+x)^{3}}\\
&\approx \frac{k}{r_{0}^{2}} + \frac{2k}{r_{0}^{3}}x - Cm(r_{0}+x) + \frac{\ell^{2}}{\mu r_{0}^{3}} - \frac{3\ell^{2}}{\mu r_{0}^{4}}x\\
&=\left(\frac{3\ell^{2}}{\mu r_{0}^{4}} + Cm - \frac{2k}{r_{0}^{3}}\right)x -\frac{k}{r_{0}^{2}} - Cmr_{0} + \frac{\ell^{2}}{\mu r_{0}^{3}}\\
&=-\left(\frac{3\ell^{2}}{\mu r_{0}^{4}} + Cm - \frac{2k}{r_{0}^{3}}\right)x
\end{align*}

where we have used that $f'(r_{0}) = 0$ and kept terms at most linear in $x$. This implies simple harmonic motion with frequency

\begin{equation*}
\omega = \sqrt{\frac{\displaystyle{\frac{3\ell^{2}}{\mu r_{0}^{4}} + Cm - \frac{2k}{r_{0}^{3}}}}{\mu}}
\end{equation*}

and again, the period is calculated as $2\pi/\omega$. My problem is with (c). What does it mean to approximate a nearly circular orbit (or any orbit, for that matter) by a precessing ellipse? I imagine the orbit as being nearly circular but oscillating about the circle with the frequency calculated in part (b); I can't picture how a precessing ellipse would approximate this, or even how to show that such an approximation is warranted.

*Edit*: In the text, the authors state that for small derivations from a circular orbit, the resulting motion can be described by

\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{r} = \frac{1}{r_{0}}+a\cos{(\beta \theta)}
\end{equation*}

where

\begin{equation*}
\beta^{2} = 3 + \frac{r}{f}\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}r}\biggr\rvert_{r=r_{0}} = \frac{\displaystyle{\frac{k}{mr_{0}^{3}}+4C}}{\displaystyle{\frac{k}{mr_{0}^{3}}+C}}.
\end{equation*}

Rearranging the first of these, we find

\begin{equation*}
r = \frac{r_{0}}{1+r_{0}a\cos{(\beta \theta)}}.
\end{equation*}

Then $r_{0}a$ seems to be some kind of eccentricity, so if I can show that $0<r_{0}a<1$, this will indicate that the orbit is approximately elliptical. Does this seem like a good approach? My intuition is still not good here, but at least it's a way forward. It also seems like I have not yet used the given assumption that the additional force is small compared to gravity. I guess it would enable me to expand $\beta^{2}$ in $C$ keeping at most linear (or even constant) terms, but I don't see the necessity.